# Resize Mathjax On Mobile

Tags: styling, mathjax

My Mathjax code looks fine on the computer but oversized on mobile: http://teach.sg/mathematics/additional-mathematics/trigonometric-functions/

[image]

Any way to resize this automatically for mobile?

Note: I am using safari on iPhone 6. Chrome gives me the same result.

Comment: If you are looking for a build-in way in MathJax, then answer is no; [`overflow: scale`](http://www.w3.org/Math/draft-spec/mathml.html#chapter2_interf.toplevel.atts) is not yet implemented.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I see, so what is the best way to resize this, whether via html or the likes?

Comment: There is an example that does this [here](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/talks/2013-01-12.jmm/sample8-mj.html) from a talk I gave several years ago.  The next page shows the source for the example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope this simple solution will fit to you:

Just add `overflow-x: scroll;` to div's style that containing MathJax equation. It will make your MathJax equation scroll-able, and prevent going equation out of range.

In your example it is a div with 
`id="std-body-box-2864" style="color:#000000; border-top-color: #56b5ff; border-left-color: #56b5ff; border-right-color: #56b5ff; border-bottom-color: #56b5ff; background-color: #ffffff;"`.

Add `overflow-x: scroll;` at the end of style tag :
`style="color:#000000; border-top-color: #56b5ff; border-left-color: #56b5ff; border-right-color: #56b5ff; border-bottom-color: #56b5ff; background-color: #ffffff; overflow-x: scroll;"`.
It will add a scroll at the bottom of the div. MathJax equation will stay in the "Special Angles" box.
Raw preview :

[image: Scroll begins]
[image: Scroll ends]
Actually there can be many solutions(including smart ones using jQuery), you can find appropriate one by googling "responsive tables in html". MathJax is using `<span>`, it's not actually the tables, but I hope that will help.

Comment: This won't be very stable given the way MathJax modifies its output (e.g., user preferences etc). Wrapping the equation in a container and setting `overflow` should work though.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger what do you mean by "wrapping the equation in a container and setting `overflow`"? I am not too familiar with HTML, I only have some basic knowledge

Answer (score 3):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61915118/mathjax-equation-does-not-fit-the-width-of-window-when-using-mobile/61942403#61942403) I found a better solution to this problem:

```
.MathJax_Display, .MJXc-display, .MathJax_SVG_Display {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```