# MathJax equation does not fit the width of window when using mobile

Tags: html, css, frontend, mathjax, hugo

In my blog post (compiled with Hugo) I have [this section](https://oren0e.github.io/2020/04/27/mab_thompson/#mathematical-proof-for-beta-distribution-being-conjugate-prior-to-bernoulli-outcome)
The math equations in this section are presented well when using a browser on a computer screen, however, when I view this on mobile the equations are being cut in the middle with no scrolling option.

I want to either resize only these equations to fit the window when accessed on mobile, or adding a scrolling option when it is needed. How can I achieve that?

I am using Markdown to write my posts. I have tried a lot of things, including adding this code to my markdown file:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    "HTML-CSS": {linebreaks: { automatic: true }}
  })
</script>
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 4):

The problematic equations are tabular environments and tables cannot linebreak.

To gain scrolling, you can add the following CSS to your page.

```
.MathJax_Display, .MJXc-display, .MathJax_SVG_Display {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

By the way, the page is using an ancient version of MathJax -- [cdn.mathjax.org was effectively shut down 3 years ago](https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/) and no longer gets updates.

Comment: Really? Whats the link to the newest?

Comment: See http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/start.html#using-mathjax-from-a-content-delivery-network-cdn.

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining what the classes being styled are and noting any version-specific information. I added this to my CSS and saw no effect.

Comment: I also tried adding it to the html header with `<script>window.MathJax = {styles: {".MathJax_Display": {"overflow-x": "auto","overflow-y": "hidden"},".MJXc-display": {"overflow-x": "auto","overflow-y": "hidden",},".MathJax_SVG_Display": {"overflow-x": "auto","overflow-y": "hidden",}}};</script>` to no effect.

Comment: @randy this answer includes CSS code, not JS. Put the code, e.g., in a style tag on your page. As for the version, these classes are for MathJax v2 which is what the question was referencing (implicitly). For MathJax v3, you'd use `mjx-container[display="true"]` as the selector (they use a custom element in v3).

Comment: I found that I needed to add `min-width: 0 ! important;` as well when using \tag (labelled formula) in MathJAX, see https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/2562#issuecomment-763930406

Comment: @heiner this is an old question (and answer) about MathJax v2 -- you link to an issue about MathJax v3 which works very differently (both in markup and layout).

Comment: The issue is the same on both versions, and the answer here works for both versions too, given the selector change you mentioned above. In both versions one needs the extra line I shared for equations with labels.